# Determining convergence/divergence of the first digit in the decimal expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, decimal-expansion

I am given a series defined by the following statement:

$a_n = $ the first digit in the decimal expression $n$

And so the sequence looks like this:

$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3$ etc.

I need to determine whether this sequence converges or diverges. My first instinct is simply to state that it is clearly infinite and non-repeating and so diverges. However I feel like there's a way to prove that is the case but can't figure out how since there's no general expression (that I can think of) for the sequence whose limit I can take.

Comment: I think you should use commas, as the sequence is $\;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,1,1....\;$ . Without commas it looks like one, single huge number. And this sequence diverges, of course, as an integers sequence converges iff it is evertually constant.

Comment: $10^n-1$ starts with $9$ while $10^n$ starts with $1$, and there are an unlimited number of examples of this, so it does not converge

Comment: That's what I figured. I am always struggling to figure out when an explanation is "sufficient" in math, when no algebraic proof is possible. But for this problem it's ok to just demonstrate the clear pattern and explain why that pattern diverges even though there's no way to create a "general" term for the sequence?

Comment: Henry's answer is a rigorous proof.  Your definition of $a_n$ is essentially already a "general term".  Henry identifies specific terms that violate convergence.

Comment: @mathematician I think Henry's comment is a good one, but is it a rigorous proof? That depends on the background of our OP.

Comment: @zhw. Okay, it's $\textit{essentially}$ rigorous.  OP certainly might write and understand the same argument in a different / more detailed way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for $n\geq1$, we have

$a_{10^n}=1$  and  $a_{2.(10^n)}=2$.

two subsequences have two different limits, so the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent.

Comment: Increasing for $n\ge 10?$ No, $a_{100} = 1.$

Comment: what i wrote is not correct. i will give right answer later.

Comment: now, it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll offer an answer that draws more on the definition of convergence and divergence of sequences. Assume for contradiction that $(a_n)$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ for some real number $L$. Then we can choose a digit $d \in \{ 1, \ldots, 9 \}$ that’s different from $L$. For every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $n \geq N$ such that $|a_n - L| \geq |d - L|$, namely $n = d 10^N$. This contradicts that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$.